# How to rewrite SQL query that has subquery with joins

Tags: mysql, join, view, subquery

I have a SQL query that has a subquery that has joins.  I would like to rewrite the query without the subquery so that I can create a view.  MySQL does not allow SELECT statements where the FROM is a subquery.

Is this possible?  I've tried removing the outer select and moving the group by inside the subs query.  This partially works but some of the data is incorrect.

```
select *
from (SELECT r.id, r.dateAdded, r.listingId, r.rating, r.username, r.valid, tbl_data.nameShort, tbl_data.desk, d.model, d.hardware, d.serial, l.appVersion, r.photoUrl, r.comment
      FROM tbl_ratings r
      JOIN tbl_data on r.listingId = vi_data.id
      JOIN tbl_devices d on r.serial = d.serial
      JOIN tbl_log l on l.serial = d.serial
      ORDER BY d.serial, l.dateAdded DESC) x
group by id
order by dateAdded DESC
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just execute the inner query?

Comment: Well I get over 7000 results instead of 350+ that I should have from tbl_ratings.  Without the group by, I am getting some duplicate information.

Comment: Are you intending to do "INNER JOIN" or "LEFT JOIN" but accidentally getting "OUTER JOIN" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple as:

```
SELECT     r.id, r.dateAdded, r.listingId, r.rating, r.username, r.valid,
           tbl_data.nameShort, tbl_data.desk, d.model, d.hardware,
           d.serial, l.appVersion, r.photoUrl, r.comment
      FROM tbl_ratings r
      JOIN tbl_data on r.listingId = vi_data.id
      JOIN tbl_devices d on r.serial = d.serial
      JOIN tbl_log l on l.serial = d.serial
      GROUP BY r.id
      ORDER BY r.dateAdded DESC
```

Also, you have a reference to "`vi_data`" that isn't anywhere else in the query

Comment: Thanks, the vi_data was an error. It should have been tbl_data.  This works however the application version is incorrect. It does not show the most recent application version. Users can run different versions of the app. In the derived table I was able to sort by l.dateAdded which gives me the most recent log information.

Comment: Consider adding a clause like "`WHERE l.appVersion = xxx`" to limit the appVersion...

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I may just skip the app version for now.  Everyone will not always have the latest version so I can't specify the app version in the query.

Comment: I redid the query as you suggested and made sure indexing was set properly and everything works -- and its fast too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `group by` clause to be `group by r.id`. Since you're selecting from a derived table (the subquery), the db can't tell that there's only one "id" field in that derived table - it only sees the column headers as specified in the subquery, which is `r.id`.

Comment: Changing id to r.id does not get rid of the subquery.  In addition, it gives me an error "Unknown column 'r.id' in 'group statement'"

Comment: You'd probably be better off aliasing all the fields, `select r.id AS rid`, and then you'd have x.rid available in the top-level query.